# C# How to go back from a window from ,where 2 different window forms lead to

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I hope the title is not very confusing. I'll try to explain it as good as i can.
I am building a virtual museum with c# at visual studio. At form1 the user can choose if he will continue unregisterd ( leads to form2) or if he will continue as registered user( leads to form3). Some options are the same for the registered and the unregisterd user and some are not. So lets say that at both form2 and form3 i have a linklabel that leads to form4 with the code

```
this.close();
Form4 myForm4 = new Form4;
myForm4.ShowDialog();
```

So far so good. At form4 i put a "previous" button.
How can i make it to go back to the form that led me to form4?
if i click the linklabel from form3 and push the previous button , i want to go to form3 and if i click from form2 i want to return to form2. 
One solution is to create similar form and go back without a problem. But i have 6 same options which means 12 new forms.
Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: For each form create Previous and Next property which will remember which forms to navigate to.

Comment: I'd suggest you reevaluate your approach as a whole. Maybe it's possible to use one form for both registered and unregistered users and just disable / hide functionality that is unavailable to unregistered users?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't close the form; hide it instead.   Execution will return to it after ShowDialog(), where you can unhide it again:

```
this.Hide();
Form4 myForm4 = new Form4;
myForm4.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

You could actually trap the result of ShowDialog() and do something different besides just unhiding the form.

A more robust approach would be to use **one** form and change what is currently displayed in it by using either UserControls or borderless forms.  Then you could have a **List** to track the order and allow easy traversal for back/forward buttons.

Comment: ... like a TabControl